# Error with load function

Tags: r

I'm new to R and im trying to do this:

```
fbOAuth(fb_appid,fb_appsec, extended_permissions = TRUE, legacy_permissions = FALSE)

fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(fb_appid,fb_appsec, extended_permissions = TRUE, legacy_permissions = FALSE)

save(fb_oauth, file="C:/Program Files/R/fb_oauth")

load("fb_oauth")
```

But gives me this errors:

```
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
cannot open compressed file 'fb_oauth', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

How can I correct this one?

Comment: what is the name of the package you are trying to download?

Comment: Did you try using `"C:/Program Files/R/fb_oauth"` in the load()?

Comment: I'm trying to load ("fb_oauth")

Comment: Yes, I tried using complete file path load("C:/Program Files/R/fb_oauth")

Comment: Is the `save()` function actually saving a file to that location?